Hollow selection in QGIS
I have performed image segmentation and overlaid the resultant polygon segments on the source image. At this stage, I will be collecting training samples by directly selecting polygons and assigning them class IDs. When I select polygons, the selection colour is opaque, making it hard to comfortably select small polygon segments forming the feature.

In the Options>Canvas & Legend, I changed the colour transparency level, but it didn't worked!. The selection is still opaque.

I am attempting to replicate the feature selection process in a manner similar to ArcGIS, as demonstrated below:

How would I enable hollow selection in QGIS?
I am using 3.36.1-Maidenhead.

Set the opacity for selection color in Project -> Properties -> General. As you can see stated in your screenshot, the Canvas & Legend options are overridden by project properties. TBH I'm not sure under what circumstances the selection color setting under Options-Canvas & Legend would actually be used.
